# ruby methods with a question mark ? for pattern matching?

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

Ruby methods that end with a question mark at the end of the name; traditionally returns true or false.

Example:

```rb
if success?
  puts "yes"
else 
  puts "oh nos"
end
```

Is there an accepted style for pattern matching that asks a question and returns [:ok] or [:error, ...]?

For example:

```
case authorization_valid?
in [:error, msg]
   puts "error: #{msg}"
in [:ok]
   puts "yes"
end
```

Instead of a true or false, we are using an :ok, :error.

[ruby methods with a question mark ? for pattern matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215249/ruby-methods-with-a-question-mark-for-pattern-matching)

Thoughts?

-daniel

Comment: This is not a suitable question for SO as "style" is vague and even if it were defined "accepted" would be subjective.

Comment: @Daniel : What is `[:ok]`  supposed to mean? In Ruby syntax, this would be a single-element Array, containing the symbol `:ok`. I can't imagine that anybody ever came up with a style guide considering such specific kinds of data.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such standard. You might be interested in using `Result` from `dry-monads`:

```rb
def method_that_return_a_result
  if condition
    Success :foo
  else
    Failure :bar
  end
end


case method_that_return_a_result
in Success(value)
  puts value
in Failure('some specific value')
  puts 'this happened, sorry'
in Failure(String => error)
  raise ProcessingError, error
in Failure(other)
  puts "Unexpected failure #{other.inspect}"
end
```

(code is just an example of what you can achieve)

Your case would read

```rb
case authorization_valid?
in Failure(msg)
  puts "error: #{msg}"
in Success
  puts "yes"
end
```